# Convert string to json object and get some data

Tags: java, android, html, json

I have a string called "response" like this:

```
{"test": {
   "id": 179512,
   "name": "Test",
   "IconId": 606,
   "revisionDate": 139844341200,
   "Level": 20
}}
```

I want to save id value to a variable. How can i do it?

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);  
jsonObj.getInt("id");
```

This dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);  
JSONObject test_jsonObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("test");  
int id = test_jsonObj.getInt("id");
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about if there is an array inside of object?

Comment: [Here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) is full documentation of JSONObject. There is a method called `getJSONArray` for such case.

Comment: @user3316779 You can get like `getJSONArray` into `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONOBject(response);
JSONObject nestedObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("test");
int id = nestedObj.getInt("id");
```